# self. in trailing swift closures, meaning and purpose?

Tags: swift, scope, closures

whenever I use a trailing closure on an action ... example:

```
run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10)){timeRemains = false}
```

I’m seeing this:

> Reference to property (*anything*) in closure requires explicitly ‘self’
>   to make capture semantics explicit.

[image]

What does this mean? And what is it on about? I'm curious because I'm only ever doing this in the context/scope of the property or function I want to call in the trailing closure, so don't know why I need `self and fascinated by the use of the word

> "semantics"

here. Does it have some profound meaning, and will I magically understand closures if I understand this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does it have some profound meaning, and will I magically understand closures if I understand this?

No and no. Or perhaps, maybe and maybe.

The reason for this syntactical demand is that this might really *be* a closure, that is, it might capture *and preserve* its referenced environment (because the anonymous function you are passing might be *stored* somewhere for a while). That means that if you refer here to some property of `self`, such as `myProperty`, you are *in fact* capturing a reference to `self`. Swift demands that you acknowledge this fact *explicitly* (by saying `self.myProperty`, not merely `myProperty`) so that *you* understand that this is what's happening.

Why do you need to understand it? Because under some circumstances you can end up with a retain cycle, or in some other way preserving the life of `self` in ways that you didn't expect. This is a way of getting you to think about that fact.

(If it is known that this particular function will *not* act as a closure, i.e. that it will be executed *immediately*, then there is no such danger and Swift will *not* demand that you say `self` explicitly.)

Comment: Excellent answer! Apple's Swift Programming Language Guide covers "Strong Reference Cycles for Closures" in detail [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID48).